# Mail sent through SQL Server Express - Mail (Id: 17) queued

Tags: sql-server, email

I followed a guide online, to send a mail through SQL Server Express, but it keeps saying "Mail (Id: 1) queued.", and up to 17, as I have tried 17 times now.

The email is a dummy mail, and not my real one. It is just an example. I use my real mail in the SQL Server Management Studio. SQL Server Express as my teacher called it.

First part of code (To create sysmail account)

```
EXECUTE msdb.dbo.sysmail_add_account_sp
    @account_name = 'MailTest',
    @description = 'Sent Mail using MSDB',
    @email_address = 'testmail@mail.com',
    @display_name = 'Landlyst',
    @username='testmail@mail.com',
    @password='password',
    @mailserver_name = 'mail.google.com'
```

Second part of code (To create Database Profile)

```
EXECUTE msdb.dbo.sysmail_add_profile_sp
    @profile_name = 'MailTest',
    @description = 'Profile used to send mail'
```

Third part of code (To add database Mail account to profile)

```
EXECUTE msdb.dbo.sysmail_add_profileaccount_sp
    @profile_name = 'MailTest',
    @account_name = 'MailTest',
    @sequence_number = 1
```

Fourth part of code (Grants permission to all)

```
EXECUTE msdb.dbo.sysmail_add_principalprofile_sp
    @profile_name = 'MailTest',
    @principal_name = 'public',
    @is_default = 1 ;
```

Fifth part of code (to enable the program to send mail, and not give an error)

```
sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;
GO
RECONFIGURE;
GO
sp_configure 'Database Mail XPs', 1;
GO
RECONFIGURE
GO
```

Sixth part of code (To send the test mail)

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail 
     @profile_name = 'MailTest', 
     @recipients = 'receiver@queryingsql.com', 
     @subject = 'Mail Test', 
     @body = 'Mail Sent Successfully', 
     @body_format = 'text'
```

I am not very good at SQL, but I need this to work as a trigger on a user.
Could someone please help me with this?

[Source](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/querying-microsoft-sql-server/2013/09/02/sending-mail-using-sql-server-express-edition/)

Comment: That (`Mail (Id: 1) queued.`) means that e-mails are put in queue and will be send as soon as possible :) Have you try to send it on real e-mails? Also to send e-mails via trigger is bad idea, because not every user is permitted to use `sp_send_dbmail`.

Comment: Yes I have tried with my real email, and that doesn't work either. I haven't recieved any mails what so ever. It has been over 5 hours now.

Comment: No spam? :) Seriously, this e-mail can get there (in SPAM directory of your mail box). Also check this `SELECT *  FROM msdb.dbo.sysmail_event_log;` for errors (event_type column)

Comment: I have looked in my spam folder, and there is only spam from all other than this.

Comment: Ok, does query show any errors?

Answer (score 0):

I ran all the same commands you did (with the profile name of 'admin') and my msdb.dbo.sysmail_log table was still empty. I additionally followed [step 5 in this link](http://www.snapdba.com/2013/04/enabling-and-configuring-database-mail-in-sql-server-using-t-sql/#.W70uD0xFxu0) which suggests running the command below (back up the registry first). I did a search in the registry to find where UseDatabaseMail and DatabaseMailProfile were. However, the command did not work, so I changed the values manually in the registry.

```
USE msdb
GO
EXEC master.dbo.xp_instance_regwrite
N'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE',
N'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.SQLEXPRESS\SQLServerAgent',
N'UseDatabaseMail',
N'REG_DWORD', 1
EXEC master.dbo.xp_instance_regwrite
N'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE',
N'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.SQLEXPRESS\SQLServerAgent',
N'DatabaseMailProfile',
N'REG_SZ',
N'admin'
```

However, this also did send my queued mail. [This link](http://expressnetsolutions.com/sqldch/?p=683) suggested trying to run the Databasemail.exe directly. I searched for 'databasemail' which was in 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\Binn'. and ran as administrator. I got the error, "The following feature couldn't be installed: .NET Framework 3.5 (includes .NET 2.0 and 3.0)"
Once .NET 3.5 was successfully installed, my queued mail was sent!